# Filter array and return object in global state with React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created simple To-Do example with React. Now I want to show popup when I clicked to To-Do element.

I stored To-Do items in global state

```
var initialState = {
      toDoList:[
        {id:1,title:"ToDo-1",description:"Desp-1",Date:"2020-02-12 00:00:01",bg:"primary",active:true,},
        {id:2,title:"ToDo-2",description:"Desp-2",Date:"2020-02-13 00:00:01",bg:"light",active:false,}
      ],
      editingItem:{},
}

export function app(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) { 
    case "GET_ITEM":
      console.log("id -> " + action.id);
      const filteredData=state.toDoList.filter((item)=>item.id===action.id);
      return Object.assign({},state,{editingItem:filteredData})  
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In main.js file

```
export default function ToDo(props) {
   const app = useSelector(state => state.app);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

    function ItemClicked(key,e){
      dispatch({ type: "GET_ITEM", id: key });
      console.log(app.editingItem);  
    }

    function CreateList(){
     return app.toDoList.map((item) => (
            <Card key={item.id} onClick={(e)=>(ItemClicked(item.id,e))}>
                <Card.Body>
                   {item.title}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
     ))
    }

   return (
     {CreateList()}
    )
}
```

When i click to To-Do element console output like this

> id -> 1
>  {}
>  id -> 2 
>   {id:1,title:"ToDo-1",description:"Desp-1",Date:"2020-02-12
>   00:00:01",bg:"primary",active:true,},
>  id -> 2 
>   {id:2,title:"ToDo-2",description:"Desp-2",Date:"2020-02-13
>   00:00:01",bg:"light",active:false,}

There is always be delay in filtered output. I see previous item. What is the problem? Should I use callback for dispatch? If so how can I use callback?

Comment: Dispatching updates the store's state, but it's only reflected in the next render phase. So you're logging too soon to be able to see the changes yet.

Comment: While not about Redux per se, [`useState` behaviour is really similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1218980) and it could help you understand how to work with `useDispatch` and `useSelector`.

Comment: One major difference is that there's no `callback` parameter on the `dispatch` function since it's not meant to be used that way. You should handle the current state in the render function only.